# Expanded and Collapse CardView not working fine

Tags: android, android-cardview

In RecyclerView, there is a problem about the adpter which assigns to every single item the ID. I use a button for every item (are CardView), and this button seems not to have a unique ID, because when I select it, it makes me expand the 1° and 13° item. I also need the expansion of the single cardview I check actually, I've notice that it expands the other cards through the list.
Why? How I can fix it?

Comment: How did you implemented expandable card view?

Comment: I have followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@akshay.shinde/cardview-expand-collapse-cd10916bb77c